# Grabbing Date from cell and it isn't formatting properly

Tags: google-sheets

I have my cell with date
[image]

```
IF(B10 <>"","Available on "&B10,"")
```

And when I try to grab the date it puts out the numbers 43837. And the cell is formatted the same as the SALE DATE cell. Am I not formatting it out properly in the cell?

I want it to say Available on January 7, 2020 just like it is i the date cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(B10 <>"","Available on " &TEXT(B10,"mmmm dd, YYYY"),"")
```

had to convert it for some reason. I guess because it mixes date and text. Thanks!